# Double linked lists in Solidity

Tags: solidity, mapping

I'm trying to build multi-threading in my contract by mapping a mapping:

```
struct Structure {
    bytes32 byteCode;
    uint integer;
}

//Mapping a structure to the address in order to hold address specific information.
mapping (address => Structure[]) mapping1;

//Mapping a mapping to uint256 in order to keep track of which thread it is concerning.
mapping (uint256 => mapping1) mapping2;
```

I am getting errors all over the contract wherever I try to do mappings like in the code above. The error is:

```
 Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
mapping (uint256 => mapping1) public mapping2;
                    ^------^
```

Any ideas about a workaround or should I just hope that next version of Solidity supports this kind of linking?

---

EDIT: I worked around the issue by using structures that have sufficient indexes in order for my mechanics to work. Unfortunately this method is way more wasteful than double linking, so I still hope someone knows the answer to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message notifies, you can't map to a dynamic var.

```
mapping (uint256 => mapping1) public mapping2;
```

should be :

```
mapping (uint256 => mapping (address => Structure[]) ) public mapping2;
```

you can use some implementations as LibCLL : https://github.com/o0ragman0o/LibCLL